# Replace whitespaces only after a match in sed or awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed, text-processing

There's this set of lines which I would need to modify

```
00:00  07:45  01. Alva 
07:45  14:40  02. White Cliffs 
14:40  20:22  03. Ribcage #1 
20:22  25:04  04. I am Oidipus
```

After a match (which could be the dot) I would need to replace whitespaces that follow, (and only those that follow) with dashes **-** or underscores **_** .

#### Expected Result:

```
00:00  07:45  01._Alva 
07:45  14:40  02._White_Cliffs 
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage_#1 
20:22  25:04  04._I_am_Oidipus
```

I've already tried the following with mixed results...

> dummyfile2 is the name of the file which I'm using to store the strings of text

```
sed -i 's/\(\.\)\(\s*\)/\1_/' dummyfile2 | sed -i 's/\(_\)\(\s*\)/\1_/' dummyfile2
```

gives result:

```
00:00  07:45 01._Alva
07:45  14:40 02._WhiteCliffs
14:40  20:22 03._Ribcage #1 
20:22  25:04 04._I am Oidipus
```

I have also tried doing the following...

```
sed -i 's/\(\.\)\(\s*\)/\1_/g' dummyfile2 | sed -i 's/\([[:alpha:]][[:space:]]\)\(\s*\)/_/g' dummyfile2
```

gives result:

```
00:00  07:45 01._Alva
07:45  14:40 02._Whit_Cliffs
14:40  20:22 03._Ribcag_#1 
20:22  25:04 04.__a_Oidipus
```

This last one was the **closest** I could come up with. (But it's not the expected result.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips Tiw! I'll consider this next time I post a question so I can make it easier to understand. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {gsub(/ /,"_",$2)}1' file

00:00  07:45  01._Alva
07:45  14:40  02._White_Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage_#1
20:22  25:04  04._I_am_Oidipus
```

Comment: That'd fail if the text after the first `.` also contained `.`s and it looks like free text to me so I don't see any reason to think it couldn't contain `.`s.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** Seems other solutions will take care of only space substituing very 1st space after `.` following will take care of all spaces.

```
awk 'match($0,/[^.]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);gsub(/ /,"_",val);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) val;next} 1' Input_file

00:00  07:45  01._Alva
07:45  14:40  02._White_Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage_#1
20:22  25:04  04._I_am_Oidipus
```

---

---

If you are trying in `sed` then following may help you. You need not to use multiple `sed` commands.

```
sed -E 's/\. +/\._/'  Input_file
00:00  07:45  01._Alva 
07:45  14:40  02._White Cliffs 
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage #1 
20:22  25:04  04._I am Oidipus
```

Change `sed -E 's/\. +/\._/'` TO `sed -E 's/\. +/\._/g'` in above in case you have multiple occurrences of `.`(spaces) in a line.

---

---

If you are ok with `awk` then could you please try following.

```
awk '{sub(/\. +/,"._")} 1' Input_file
```

If you have multiple occurrences of `.` then replace `sub` with `gsub` in above command. Output will be as follows.

```
00:00  07:45  01._Alva 
07:45  14:40  02._White Cliffs 
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage #1 
20:22  25:04  04._I am Oidipus
```

***Tested above code with multiple spaces:*** Let's say we have multiple spaces after `.` then also aboe code will work. Assuming uyour Input_file is as follows.

```
cat Input_file
00:00  07:45  01. Alva 
07:45  14:40  02. White Cliffs 
14:40  20:22  03. Ribcage #1 
20:22  25:04  04.   I am Oidipus
```

Here I have changed the last line added more spaces after `.`, now after running code it will replace them with single `_` as follows.

```
awk '{sub(/\. +/,"._")} 1' Input_file
00:00  07:45  01._Alva 
07:45  14:40  02._White Cliffs 
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage #1 
20:22  25:04  04._I am Oidipus
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\s+\</_/3g' file
```

Replace the third group of whitespace prior to a word and onwards by an `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
$ perl -pe ' s/(?:\S+)\. (.+)$/$x=$&;$x=~s! !_!g;$x/ge ' whitespace.txt
00:00  07:45  01._Alva
07:45  14:40  02._White_Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage_#1
20:22  25:04  04._I_am_Oidipus

$
```

Comment: Simpler: `perl -pe's/\.\K(.+)$/$1=~s{\s+}{_}gr/ge' whitespace.txt`

Comment: (Starts replacing after the first `.`.  To go from the last, `s/.*\.\K.../`)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed, you can do it like this:

```
sed -E ':a;s/(\.\S*)\s+(\S+)/\1_\2/;ta'
```

Example (added one edge case):

```
$ cat file
00:00  07:45  01. Alva
07:45  14:40  02. White Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03. Ribcage #1
20:22  25:04  04. I am Oidipus
20:22  25:04  05.U re  spe   cial

$ sed -E ':a;s/(\.\S*)\s+(\S+)/\1_\2/;ta' file
00:00  07:45  01._Alva
07:45  14:40  02._White_Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage_#1
20:22  25:04  04._I_am_Oidipus
20:22  25:04  05.U_re_spe_cial
```

POSIX sed compliant:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/\(\.[^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*\)/\1_\2/;' -e 'ta' file
```

If you are sure there's no trailing spaces in your lines or you want the trailing spaces be replaced too, you can remove the second catch group ( `(...)` or `\(...\)` ) and the `\2`.

Comment: You don't need second backreference. Same output with `sed -E ':a;s/(\.\S*) /\1_/;ta' file`.

Comment: @SLePort  There're tailing spaces in OP's sample data, and obviously OP don't want the tailing spaces got replaced by underscore. Also we can interpret OP's intention by the code `(\s*\)` to `_` that OP want to replace consecutive multiple spaces with only one `_`.

Comment: There is nothing obvious about the way OP wants to handle trailing spaces. And it's sample data, not a source file. Trailing spaces may be the result of copy&paste.

Comment: @SLePort  C&P won't cause that, it could be OP's formatting error when post the question. Anyway, it's the safe way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'p=index($0,"."){tl=substr($0,p+1); gsub(/ /,"_",tl); $0=substr($0,1,p) tl} 1' file
00:00  07:45  01._Alva
07:45  14:40  02._White_Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage_#1
20:22  25:04  04._I_am_Oidipus
```

or with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([^.]+.)(.*)/,a){$0=a[1] gensub(/ /,"_","g",a[2])} 1' file
00:00  07:45  01._Alva
07:45  14:40  02._White_Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage_#1
20:22  25:04  04._I_am_Oidipus
20:22  25:04  05._here_is_a_dot._that_may_hurt._idk.
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed(POSIX-compliant):

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\(\.[^ ]*\) /\1_/;ta' file
```

If you want to replace consecutives spaces with only one `_`:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\(\.[^ ]*\)  */\1_/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With Procedural Text Edit, you can achieve it like so:

```
forEach line {
  select (after ci ".") { findReplace ci " " "_" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of great answers. I am new to `awk` but here is one easy solution

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="  "} {gsub(/ /, "_", $3); print $0}' InputFile
```

Here is my `InputFile`

```
00:00  07:45  01. Alva
07:45  14:40  02. White Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03. Ribcage #1
20:22  25:04  04. I am Oidipus
```

and here is the `output` after `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="  "} {gsub(/ /, "_", $3); print $0}' InputFile`

```
00:00  07:45  01._Alva
07:45  14:40  02._White_Cliffs
14:40  20:22  03._Ribcage_#1
20:22  25:04  04._I_am_Oidipus
```

Explanation:
   BEGIN = this block of code gets executed before the file read , meaning all the variables can be declared here

FS = Field Separator = two spaces (recognized a new field after every two continue spaces from the InputFile

OFS = Output Field Separator = two spaces (recognized a new field after every two continue spaces in the output ..just like the Inputdata

`gsub(/ /, "_", $3)` replacing one space " " with underscore _ in column 3 ($3)

and finally, printed the each row till the file ended

```
{print $0}
```